# Integrate SVN into an existing project

Tags: svn, version-control, versioning, ubersvn

I need some help implementing SVN into an existing project.

Currently, I have the project production copy on:

/home/www/myproject

But there are some files and folders that I DON'T want to track with SVN like:

/home/www/myproject/images/

/home/www/myproject/static_info.txt

How do I add SVN to this environment without breaking something on the production copy? And without adding to the repository the files/folders that I want to exclude.

And most importantly, what will be the best way to keep the production copy updated automatically after each commit.

Right now I just have set up a blank repo. on /opt/ubersvn/repositories/myproject using UberSVN...

I have read this other question:

[Adding version control to an existing project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117426/best-way-to-add-version-control-to-existing-project)

But I still feel lost (I have never used SVN before).

Comment: Are you sure you want SVN? Systems like mercurial or git provide a superset of SVN functionality and will give you less headache.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I would like to implement Git instead, seems easier to use, but someone else decided we would use SVN and I have to set up the repo. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding images and static_info.txt - look at svn:ignore properties, that will allow you to exclude files from versioning:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html

As for automatic updates, you could look at post commit hooks:

https://mikewest.org/2006/06/subversion-post-commit-hooks-101

You could write a script that will automatically go from there and update the production environment. The emphasis is on "could". It sounds like a straight forward way to break production with an erroneous commit, you might want to test for breakage before you do that.

Also, since svn creates .svn folders all over the place, you should make sure that doesn't interfere with your environment, but I can not really help you here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would import and then make a check out be a good way to achieve my goal? My main fear is that some files get erased while making the check out, or that it takes too much time and end up breaking the production copy. =/

Comment: There is only one way to find out ;-) You should in any case make a backup first and try it offline, as for your specific application - I have no knowledge about it, do you have to recompile it? Do you need to restart it? I don't know, you will have to figure this out.

Comment: +1 for the comment about automatically breaking production.  What my team does is to export to a test server (no .svn folders on production), verify that the test server is working, and only then copying the exported files to the production system.  To avoid the problem of a newer revision removing some files, always export to a clean directory and then use rsync, robocopy or similar to do all the needed updates.

Comment: @Michael It's just a Php based website so it doesn't require recompile or anything. I will give it a try to the import and then check out approach. Thanks for all the help!